# sql - How to order by using other field as sort order?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table with two fields, name and date, let's say:

```
name   |   date
A         1/12/15
D         1/11/15
C         1/11/15
A         1/10/15
C         1/09/15
B         1/09/15
A         1/08/15
```

I want to sort it by name, so that all the ones of the same name appear together, but sorted by date, so that the first names will be the ones with the more recent date.

So I would get:

```
name   |   date
A         1/12/15
A         1/10/15
A         1/08/15
D         1/11/15
C         1/11/15
C         1/09/15
B         1/09/15
```

Because if I use `orderby name, date desc`; then the names are ordered alphabetically and I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

Join the table with itself, where you group by the name and get the latest date for each name. Then you can sort by the latest date, then by name (to get the same names together where the latest date happens to be the same), then by date.

```
select
  t.name,
  t.date
from
  TheTable as t
  inner join (
    select
      name,
      max(date) as date
    from
      TheTable
    group by
      name
  ) as x on x.name = t.name
order by
  x.date desc,
  t.name,
  t.date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want ([see SQL Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/cec9d/4)):

```
SELECT n1.name, n1.dt
  FROM nd n1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT name, MAX(dt) AS max_dt
      FROM nd
     GROUP BY name
  ) n2
   ON n1.name = n2.name
ORDER BY n2.max_dt DESC, n1.dt DESC
```

Keep in mind that because both `C` and `D` have a most recent date of `1/11/2015` that which one comes first is undefined without an additional sort.